# Advice on SQL how to pull three tables into one while adding two columns with matched or unmatched indicator

Tags: sql

I have three tables all with the same columns: patient id, location, weight.

Table 1 contains everyone with a weight.

Table 2 is a subset of Table 1, it is everyone who was in Table 1 and participates in program A.

Table 3 is a subset of Tale 1, it is everyone who was in Table 1 and participates in program B.

What I would like to do is create a summary table with the following columns:
patient id, location, weight, program A (yes or no), program B (yes or no)

I just spent 2-3 hours trying different functions and hitting dead ends trying to come up with code to achieve the desired result.  Hopefully i am missing something easy.  Thanks in advance for any help anyone is able to provide!

Comment: Why do tables 2 and 3 contain the location and weight? This seems superfluous. What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I think this database design can be improved quite a bit the query you need can look like:

```
select
  p.*,
  case when a.patient_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as program_a,
  case when b.patient_id is null then 'no' else 'yes' end as program_b  
from table1 p
left join table2 a on a.patient_id = p.patient_id
left join table3 b on b.patient_id = p.patient_id
```

**Note**: Again, I would suggest you normalize this database design, at least to 3NF.

Comment: Thank you!  This looks like it will work perfectly.  Being an infrequent user of SQL I tend to write redundant code during my first drafts.  I realize you are correct in identifying this as not the most efficient coding to obtain the desire outcome.  I will work on tightening it up in future drafts.  Thanks again!